# Manage roster modifictions true external webapp and disable for users?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, rostering

I have a webapp that's a game, and only after certain score people can become friends and should be automatically added to each other friendlist.

Trying to figure out how to handle rosters in Ejabberd like this

- prevent any user from adding anyone else by him/herself
- only let webapp handle modifications to rosters  ( buddylist )

Using a client JS library like strophe would not be secure I need serverside method of adding users to each others roster. Any thoughts ideas on how to do this with Ejabberd?

EDIT:
Ok, it seems mod_rest for ejabberd gives restfull access to (all?) the ejabbard methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after I was on the right track I managed to figure it out in an hour..

- install ejabberd
- install mod_rest
- install mod_admin_extra

command:

```
ejabberdctl help process_rosteritems
```

:

```
Command Name: process_rosteritems

  Arguments: action::string
             subs::string
             asks::string
             users::string
             contacts::string

  Returns: res::rescode

  Tags: roster 

  Description: List or delete rosteritems that match filtering options 

Explanation of each argument:
 - action: what to do with each rosteritem that matches all the filtering options
 - subs: subscription type
 - asks: pending subscription
 - users: the JIDs of the local user
 - contacts: the JIDs of the contact in the roster

Allowed values in the arguments:
 ACTION = list | delete
 SUBS = SUB[:SUB]* | any
 SUB = none | from | to | both
 ASKS = ASK[:ASK]* | any
 ASK = none | out | in
 USERS = JID[:JID]* | any
 CONTACTS = JID[:JID]* | any
 JID = characters valid in a JID, and can use the globs: *, ?, ! and [...]

This example will list roster items with subscription 'none', 'from' or 'to' that have any ask property, of local users which JID is in the virtual host 'example.org' 
and that the contact JID is either a bare server name (without user part) or that has a user part and the server part contains the word 'icq':
 list none:from:to any *@example.org *:*@*icq*
```